# Define an array wrapped in styling

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to wrap a value in HTML like the following example?

```
$email_message = ('somehtml', $emailtext, 'somemorehtml');
```

So that when it is run you get:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <style>body {color:#eee;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello and welcome to our website</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML and PHP are invalid and I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Could you please explain your goal more clearly?

Comment: see Ashley Banks answer below, thats basically what I need, I know the php and html are invalid, its just an rough example I typed out in notepad, my coding is even more useless without help from the likes of dreamweaver.

Comment: for future reference when asking a question like this try to make your samples match up with each other so it is clear where the intended output is supposed to come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$msg = 'Hello and welcome to our website';
$body = '<html>
         <head><style>body {color:#eee;}</style></head>
         <body>
         <p>' . $msg . '</p>
         </body
         </html>';

 echo $body;
```

?

Comment: YES thats what I am looking for, I will give that a go, I just want sure how on earth to code it

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a templating system.

[jQuery Templating](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx) - for doing it on the client

[PHP TAL](http://phptal.org/) - for doing it with PHP on the server

Comment: My preference would be for Twig over TAL, but this is a good guess at the OPs intentions.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible but it's not the best practice.
it would be better to do:

```
<html>
<head><style>body {color:#eee;}</style></head>
<body>
<p>Hello and welcome to our website, Mr <?php echo $name; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

do you absolutely need to echo your html?

Comment: He might be wanting to do it for an email, judging from the variable '$email_message'. Although it would be better for him to use just the HTML within a html file and use file_get_contents and replace some tags within that?

Comment: if that is the case, i'd personally use a templating engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [TAL](http://phptal.org/) like @Diodeus said... but again that depends on what your needs are